# How to make a secure communication between nodes for replication?

Tags: ssl, couchdb, replication

I searched for the best way to estabilsh a replication between two servers with CouchDB but I do not find any infomation on it. The manual in https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/setup/cluster.html does not talk about this.

I am using a SSH permanent connection between the two servers using a certificate without passthrough:

```
ssh -f -L 127.0.0.1:5985:127.0.0.1:5984 sinccouchdb@100.100.100.100 -N -i id_rsa_sinccouchdb -l sinccouchdb -o ServerAliveInterval=60
```

But I am not sure if this is the best way. Anyone can point me to a better and secure solution?

Comment: I guess you only have to setup HTTPS on your CouchDB node and then replicate through HTTPS instead of HTTP. Documentation [here](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/config/http.html#https-ssl-tls-options)

Comment: As this is not a programming question, it would be a better fit on ServerFault.

Comment: Duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/1003301/couchdb-how-to-make-a-secure-communication-between-nodes-for-replication